# Laço de repetição - Python

Tags: python, loop

Eu preciso criar um código que eu coloque o nome do aluno, a idade e ele me mostre de acordo com uma tabela que tenho se esse aluno está no ensino infantil, fundamental I, fundamental II e ensino médio, pois bem, consegui desenvolver essa parte porem no final ele deve aparecer a mensagem " Deseja continuar com o programa: 0-Não    1-Sim" ai está o problema, não estou conseguindo realizar está etapa.

deixo meu código abaixo:

```
nome= input('Qual o nome da criança? ')
idade= int(input('Qual a idade da criança? '))
while(s != '1'):
  if idade <= 5:
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino infantil'.format(nome, idade))
  elif idade <=6 or idade <=10: 
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino fundamental I'.format(nome, idade))
  elif idade <=11 or idade <=14: 
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino fundamental II'.format(nome, idade))
  elif idade >=15:
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ansino médio'. format(nome, idade))
s= input('Deseja continuar com o programa? 0-Não    1-Sim')
```

Comment: Ajeite a endentação da ultima linha de fique aninhada com o laço de repetição. Python é sensível ao recuo.

Comment: Obrigado, mas ele não retorna no inicio! quando chega ao fim ele encerra.

Comment: Aqui `while(s != '1'):` *enquanto s não for igual a '1' repita*. Declare `s='1'` antes do `while` e mude o laço para `while(s == '1'):`

Comment: `elif idade <=6 or idade <=10` - isso significa "*se a idade é menor ou igual a 6, ou se a idade é menor ou igual a 10*". Mas se ela for menor que 6, também será menor que 10, então testar as duas coisas é redundante, poderia ser apenas `elif idade <= 10`

Comment: Aliás, dá pra simplificar: https://ideone.com/bLom58

Comment: @hkotsubo, eu copiei o seu código para uma resposta. Espero que não tenha problemas.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sem problemas 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até o python versão 3.9 você pode implementar esse algoritmo conforme o
[@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) o ensinou nos [comentários da pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/533540/la%C3%A7o-de-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-python/533557#comment962811_533540)

```python
#O fragmento a seguir é cópia ipsis litteris do algoritmo https://ideone.com/bLom58
#de autoria do usuário @hkotsubo, perfil https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo
while True:
    nome = input('Qual o nome da criança? ')
    idade = int(input('Qual a idade da criança? '))
    if idade <= 5:
        classe = 'ensino infantil'
    # se não entrou no primeiro if é porque com certeza é maior que 5,
    # então só preciso testar se é menor ou igual a 10
    elif idade <= 10:
        classe = 'ensino fundamental I'
    # se não entrou no if e no elif acima é porque com certeza é maior que 10,
    # então só preciso testar se é menor ou igual a 14
    elif idade <= 14:
        classe = 'ensino fundamental II'
    # se não entrou em nenhum if/elif é porque com certeza é maior que 14,
    # então se chegou aqui é porque com certeza é maior ou igual a 15 e não preciso testar
    else:
        classe = 'ensino médio'
 
    print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos e está matriculado no {classe}')
    # pra que variável? Compare direto o que foi digitado
    if input('Deseja continuar com o programa? 0-Não    1-Sim') != '1':
        break # sai do while
```

A partir da versão python 3.10 foi implementada a [PEP 634 -- Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) e o algoritmo pode ser implementado da seguinte forma:

```python
while True:
    nome = input('Qual o nome da criança? ')
    idade = int(input('Qual a idade da criança? '))
    match idade:
        case i if i<=5:
            classe = 'ensino infantil'
        case i if i <= 10:
            classe = 'ensino fundamental I'
        case i if i <= 14:
            classe = 'ensino fundamental II'
        case _:
            classe = 'ensino médio'
    print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos e está matriculado no {classe}')
    if input('Deseja continuar com o programa? 0-Não    1-Sim') != '1':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro passo é definir a variável s = '1' fora do laço de repetição. Os parâmetros do laço devem ser while(s == '1'), e, os três inputs devem estar dentro do laço.

```
s = '1'
while(s == '1'):
  nome= input('Qual o nome da criança? ')
  idade= int(input('Qual a idade da criança? '))
  if idade <= 5:
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino infantil'.format(nome, idade))
  elif idade <=6 or idade <=10: 
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino fundamental I'.format(nome, idade))
  elif idade <=11 or idade <=14: 
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino fundamental II'.format(nome, idade))
  elif idade >=15:
    print('{} tem {} anos e está matriculado no ensino médio'. format(nome, idade))
  s= input('Deseja continuar com o programa? \n0-Não    \n1-Sim  \n ')
```

Comment: É só seguir o que [está nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/533540/la%c3%a7o-de-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o-python#comment962793_533540). Está ruim esse código.