# Problema com código simples em Python

Tags: python

```
nome = input('Nome da criança:')
id = int(input('Idade:'))
if (id <= 5):
  print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Infantil'.format(nome, id))
elif (id >= 6) and (id <= 10):
  print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Fundamental I'.format(nome, id))
elif (id >= 11) and (id <= 14):
  print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Fundamental II'.format(nome, id))
elif (id > 15):
  print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Médio'.format(nome, id))

int(input('Deseja continuar?  0 - Não      1 - Sim'))
Sim = 1
Nao = 0
if 0:
 print('Encerrando o programa')
```

Estou com um problema pra finalizar esse código, pode ser um erro simples porém estou começando e estou quebrando a cabeça pra resolver.

Preciso que ele exiba na tela a mensagem de ''Encerrando o programa'' caso a pessoa escolha, porém quando dou o comando pra encerrar por exemplo, ele não exibe o print na tela e simplesmente finaliza. Preciso também que caso a pessoal escolha continuar, ele volte ao inicio perguntando o nome da criança.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/533540/112052

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Lucas, você precisa de algo que repita caso o usuário queria continuar, para isso podemos usar varias formas, uma delas é usar o comando `while`, que repete algo até que sua condição não seja mais satisfeita.

No exemplo abaixo, e usando como base o seu código, criei a variável `continuar` atribuindo inicialmente o valor de 1, dessa forma garantimos que vai entrar a primeira vez na repetição, até porque o "sim" seria o valor "1".

Abaixo dos seus condicionais, atribui o valor da resposta a própria variável, que após última linha de execução do bloco do `while`, vai automaticamente sair da repetição.

```py
continuar = 1
while continuar==1:
    nome = input('Nome da criança:')
    id = int(input('Idade:'))
    if (id <= 5):
      print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Infantil'.format(nome, id))
    elif (id >= 6) and (id <= 10):
      print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Fundamental I'.format(nome, id))
    elif (id >= 11) and (id <= 14):
      print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Fundamental II'.format(nome, id))
    elif (id > 15):
      print('O aluno {} tem {} anos e está no Ensino Médio'.format(nome, id))
    
    continuar = int(input('Deseja continuar?  0 - Não      1 - Sim'))
    
    if continuar==0:
      print('Encerrando o programa')
```